# Trying to run a flatpak install of Plex Media Player and it instantly closes

Tags: flatpak

If I click on the icon in the app launcher PMP briefly flashes open but closes straight away.

If I run `flatpak run tv.plex.PlexMediaPlayer` in the terminal PMP briefly flashes open and closes and I get the following message:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Logging to /home/alex/.var/app/tv.plex.PlexMediaPlayer/data/plexmediaplayer/logs/plexmediaplayer.log
Logging to /home/alex/.var/app/tv.plex.PlexMediaPlayer/data/plexmediaplayer/logs/pmphelper.log
```

Not sure how to fix it and get Plex Media Player to open.

Comment: Anything useful in those log files? `/home/alex/.var/app/tv.plex.PlexMediaPlayer/data/plexmediaplayer/logs/plexmediaplayer.log` and `Logging to /home/alex/.var/app/tv.plex.PlexMediaPlayer/data/plexmediaplayer/logs/pmphelper.log`

Comment: Not that I can see. https://pastebin.com/7UDFgb4Q

```
2021-09-10 10:33:05 [ DEBUG ] HelperMain.cpp @ 50 - Helper ( "2.58.0.dev-ae73e074" ) up and running 
2021-09-10 10:33:05 [ INFO  ] LocalJsonServer.cpp @ 33 - Listening to socket: "/tmp/pmp_pmpHelper_alex.sock" 
```